# font-size of inline child doesn't take effect

Tags: html, css

I can set span's font-size normally.

When it's bigger than the h1's font-size, it does work:

```
<style>
h1 {
    font-size: 1em;
}

span {
    font-size: 2em;
}
</style>

<h1>Normal text, <span>bigger one</span></h1>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/We9nu/

The inverse doesn't work. I've tried with "!important" too:

```
<style>
h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
}

span {
    font-size: 1em;
}
</style>

<h1>Bigger text, <span>normal one</span></h1>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FGV5Z/1/

Is it possible to do it with this HTML markup?

I've tested with Firefox and Chromium.

Thanks.

Comment: you should know about `em` unit first..

Comment: I completely forgot this behaviour. With Fabrizio Calderan's response, it's clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the second example you need to do

```
h1   {  font-size: 2em; }
span {  font-size: .5em; // half of parent element }
```

if you set `1em` in a child element you're actually defining the same font-size of the parent element, because ems are multiplying (`2em * 1em` is still `2em`, while `2em * 0.5em` is `1em` as resulting font-size)

See [this resource](http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/) about available font units and how they work

Answer (score 3):

Define font size in pixels :

```
<style>
h1 {
   font-size: 12px;
}

span {
   font-size: 24px;
}
```

inverse will also works.